# About egrep command

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

How can I create a bash script that admits a file as a command line argument and prints on screen all lines that have a length of more than 12 characters using egrep command?

Comment: Why do you want to use `egrep`? It's not the best tool for this job.

Comment: I need to learn this tool because it's my exam topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
egrep '.{13}'
```

The `.` will match any character, and the `{13}` repeats it exactly 13 times. You can put this in a shell script like:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Make sure the user actually passed an argument. This is useful
# because otherwise grep will try and read from stdin and hang forever
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo "Filename needed"
  exit 1
fi

egrep '.{13}' "$1"
```

The `$1` refers to the first command argument. You can also use `$2`, `$3`, etc, and `$@` refers to *all* commandline arguments (useful if you want to run it over multiple files):

```
egrep '.{13}' "$@"
```